# compensating for the status bar at the top of the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm not sure what it's called. Status bar? With the reception and batter life on. But is there an easy way to tell if it's displaying in an app?

I'm writing some generic code and I want something to be positioned right at the top of the screen if there isn't a bar, and below the bar if there is. People should be able to just dump my code into their project and it should just work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
BOOL hidden = [UIApplication sharedApplication].isStatusBarHidden;
```

And yes, it's called status bar.

Comment: would you happen to know what doing this as a parameter: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height]` causes the error: expected identifier?

Comment: yes, it's because you're using the objective-c message syntax wrong.

This works:
 CGFloat someHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

and this doesn't:
CGFloat someHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height];
,
because in the first case you say:
CGFloat height = [gettheheight];
and in the second: CGFloat height = [[gettheheight]andExpectMessage];.

SO, to wrap it up, you use one set of brackets too many.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you put something with frame origin at (0, 0) it will take into account if status bar is visible or not - the views will be resized/pushed down using their autoresize masks.

Comment: maybe my code is in the wrong place but if i set it to 0, 0 it's behind the bar

Comment: if the `statusBarStyle` of the app is transparent, then the contained view is "behind" the status bar